# Checking if database row exists using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm busy on a register form, but the biggest part is jQuery. So I wanna validate the inputs using jQuery too. After lots of thinking, this is what I came up with;

```
$('#usernameDone').click(function() 
    {
        $.post('public/robin/check_existing.php',{value: $("#username").val()}, function(data){
window.alert(data);
if(data == true){
    window.alert("Name exists");
}else{
    window.alert("Name doesnt exist");
}
    });
```

(I know the 'click' function isn't closed, but that's because there's some stuff after it.)

So it posts the value of the `#username` input field into `check_existing.php`, which looks like this;

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['value'];
$db = new MySQLi('127.0.0.1', 'root', '*******', 'htv1.1');
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM ht_users WHERE naam = ?');
$query->bind_param('s', $value);
$query->execute();
if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Please note this is not the method I normally use. This was more like a 'testbench'.

The only thing is; it always returns one empty alert box, and then it shows 'name doesnt exist'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` return anyway?

Comment: @Ghost At a guess, exactly the same thing that the `alert` is showing :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe i just wanted to know if its `true (string)` or `true (bool)` anyway, it doesn't matter, the answers already picked and helped the OP

Comment: @Ghost but it's blank - so it won't be anything?

Comment: @JamesThorpe It shows `true` or `false`

Comment: @RobinBerg With the change to `echo` in the PHP it will show `true` or `false`, yes.  You may need to change the `if` statement as per Ed's answer too

Comment: @JamesThorpe I actually did that. Thanks for that Ed. Now, the thing is; it always returns false, even tho I'm testing with a name that exists for sure...

-- EDIT --

Never minds. It works now. I requested the userID and used `store_result()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `return` statement in PHP is just stopping execution.  You need to send the data to the actual response, eg using `echo`:

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

The first javascript `alert` is blank as no data is being returned from PHP, which evaluates as `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the andswer, the only thing is, it always returns false... I'm testing it with a name that does exist for sure in the db, and it alway says 'name doesn't exist'

Answer (score 0):

Change the PHP to read

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

Then the JS to read

```
if(data == "true"){
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you are using $.POST wrong. 'data' can never have any value in your code. It is and will be undefined.

Look at the code from the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Here is a snipped that should work:

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  alert(data);
  // Go ahead with your code.
});
```

So use an anonymous function that takes (data) and proceed from there.

Comment: The `POST` is fine - it's clearly PHP not returning any data.  the function here is the 3rd parameter to `POST` which is the callback function and is passed the returned data by jQuery

Comment: Sorry - it was a browser viewport issue. I missed the 3rd parameter and didn't proceed looking at the 'return' inside the php method - my bad.